# How to move some code from post method to a separate method in Django views

Tags: python, django, view

I have a class that take some info from a form, make some changes to it. And than saves it into database
At the moment all the logic is in the post method. And I want to make the code more structured and I want to put some part of it to a separate method. Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

here is my code:

```
class AddSiteView(View):
    form_class = AddSiteForm
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, { 'form': form })
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            site_instanse = form.save()
            url = request.POST.get('url', '')
            if url.endswith('/'):
                url = url + "robots.txt" 
            else:
                url = url + "/robots.txt"

            robot_link = Robot(
                site = site_instanse,
                link = url,
                )
            robot_link.save()
            pk = Robot.objects.get(site=site_instanse)
            
            return redirect('checks:robots', pk.id)
        
        return render(request, self.template_name, { 'form': form })
```

I want to make 2 changes to it:
The 1st thing I want to do is to move this part of code to a separate method

```
if url.endswith('/'):
    url = url + "robots.txt" 
else:
    url = url + "/robots.txt"
```

And the 2nd thing I want to do is to move this part of code also in a separate method

```
robot_link = Robot(
                site = site_instanse,
                link = url,
                )
robot_link.save()
pk = Robot.objects.get(site=site_instanse)
return redirect('checks:robots', pk.id)
```

The reason is that I will be adding more functions here. And I don't want to have it all in post method. If it is possible, please, help me. I've already tried several ways of solving this problem, but they didn't work
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about Django preventing you from using plain python functions. So, if you know how to define methods and functions, you should take the same approach. For example, the first part can be the function

```
def get_robots_url(url):
    if url.endswith('/'):
        url = url + "robots.txt" 
    else:
        url = url + "/robots.txt"
    return url
```

Then you call the extracted function in the same place

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        site_instance = form.save()
        url = request.POST.get('url', '')
        url = get_robots_url(url)
    ....
```

You can also define a function inside the class - a method, to group the code. For the 2nd part:

```
class AddSiteView(View):
...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            site_instanse = form.save()
            url = request.POST.get('url', '')
            url = get_robots_url(url)
            return self.create_robot(site_instanse, url)
        return render(request, self.template_name, { 'form': form })

    def create_robot(self, site_instance, url):
        robot_link = Robot(
            site = site_instanse,
            link = url,
            )
        robot_link.save()
        pk = Robot.objects.get(site=site_instance)
        return redirect('checks:robots', pk.id)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives an error: site_instance is not defined

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've used your advice. But now I have another problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62892652/how-to-pass-a-variable-between-methods-inside-django-class-based-view Maybe you have the idea how to fix it

Comment: there is a typo in the variable name. it is instanCe, not instanSe

Comment: I've fixed the typo and now everything works fine 
Thank you very much! You helped me a lot